# filling a two dimentional array with a for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to make a two-dimensional array from 8x8 which will be filled by a for loop. The table has to begin with the number 32 and every following number should decrease by 1.

This is my attempted solution of the problem:

```
public class Inzend2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int [] [] blastTable = new int [8] [8]; 

        for(int i = 32; i < blastTable.length; i--) {
            for(int j = i; j < blastTable.length; j--) {
                System.out.println( blastTable[i][j]);
            }            
        } 

    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong? (nothing is printed when I run the program)

Comment: the outer for loop never executes because `i` is initialized to 32 which is > blastTable.length. The 2D array has length 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly:** An 8x8 array has 64 entries.

**Secondly:** To print the value, you have to assign it first.

**Thirdly:** Use a counter to fill your array. You are iterating not in the bounds of your array. So you start with blastTable[32][32] but this is nocht smaller 8 what is the condition in your for loop.

```
for(int i = 32; i < blastTable.length; i--) {
//means: set i = 32; as long as i < blastTable.lenght (8) proceed the loop;
//       after each iteration decrease i by one
```

One correct way would be:

```
int counter = 32;   //or 64
for(int i = 0; i < blastTable.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < blastTable[i].length; j++) {
        blastTable[i][j] = counter;
        counter--;
        System.out.println( blastTable[i][j]);
    }            
}
```

This code would fill all numbers from from 32 to -31 into your array (or 64 to 1) and print them.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work. You have an array (length 8) of arrays (each of length 8). The outer for loop iterates over the first array, the inner for loop iterates over the contained arrays.

Note that you haven't initialized your array with any values.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
   int [] [] blastTable = new int [8] [8]; 

   for(int i = blastTable.length; i > 0; i--) {
      for(int j = blastTable.length; j > 0; j--) {
         System.out.println( blastTable[i][j]);
      }
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying in a wrong way.Because the row size is 8 not 32.And your array elements is uninitialized,every elements will have the default value of 0.Try this to print the value of elements:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   int [] [] blastTable = new int [8] [8]; 

   for(int i = 0; i < blastTable.length; i++) {
     for(int j = 0; j < blastTable[i].length; j++) {
       System.out.println( blastTable[i][j]);
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some considerations:

1. 8x8 is 64, so if you start from 32 are you accepting that last number is -31, correct? Or you want to start from 64 and have 1 as last number?
2. You can solve it without using a third counter, but it is more simple to use it, so try the following sample.

Sample:

```
int count = 32; // or 64 as I proposed before
int[][] blastTable = new int[8][8]; 

for(int i = 0; i < blastTable.length; ++i) {
  for(int j = 0; j < blastTable.length; ++j) {
    blastTable[i][j] = count--;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, it's correct that the last number is -31. I 'm just starting with learning java and I was confused because the number has to decrease but you're all right that I first have to use the ++ in the loop to fill the array 8 x 8 times.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your table is not initialized.
Second, the table's size is 8 not 32
The first loop will go through the lines of the table and second loop will go through the columns(since we are talking about a two-dimentinal table)
The first loop should begin with i = blastTable.length
The second loop should begin with j = blastTable.length

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment your row and column indexes while at the same time decrementing your start value of 32.

```
public static void initializeTable(int[][] blastTable, int startValue) {
    for (int i = 0; i < blastTable.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < blastTable[i].length; j++) {
            blastTable[i][j] = startValue--;
            System.out.println( blastTable[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for thinking with me all! I fixed it and this is my final result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int [] [] blastTable = new int [8] [8];

    int counter = 32;

    for(int i = 0; i < blastTable.length; i++) {

        for(int j = 0; j < blastTable[i].length; j++) {
            blastTable[i][j] = counter;
            counter--;
            System.out.print(blastTable[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

}
```